# can you do string replacement using only the JSON spec?

Tags: json, node.js

I want to reference a value within the JSON object later in the object.  I've found you can do it using `$ref`, but I can't inject that into a value with other data.  Is there a way to perform what I'm looking for?  A (non-working) example of what I'm looking for is below.

```
{
  "driver": {
    "name": "George"
  },
  "driveFast": {
    "question": "does " + { "$ref": "#/driver/name" } + " Drive fast?"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which language or enviroment are you working in?

Comment: nodejs, but I don't want to have to write custom node code to do it if at all possible.